# Converting FBX Camera Movement from Millimeters to Meters

Tags: camera, .fbx

I have a camera movement in an FBX file that I exported from After Effects, and I want to import it into Blender. The problem is that the location appears in millimeter values and with a very small movement range, for example, the Y-axis first point is at 0.004987 and the second point in the animation is at 0.004988.

I need to convert all the keyframes in the animation to meter values, meaning to move the point three places to the right - so the location would actually be 4.987 and the second point 4.988 meters.

How can I perform this conversion?

Answer (score 0):

You can just scale all keys on the y axis.

First open the *Graph Editor*, select a keyframe with a value of `0`, press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> and then select *Cursor to Selection*.

This will ensure that all values will be scaled relative to `0`, so all positive values will remain positive and all negative values will remain negative.

Next set the pivot point to *2D Cursor* (the one you just set to `0`). It's the icon to the left of the magnet icon/snap option.

Now you can select all keys and scale them on the Y axis by `1000`.